# How can I resolve a syntax error near keyword "INNER" for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
            USCounties2010.STUSAB,
            USCounties2010.P0010001,
            USCounties2000.p0010001,
            ROUND(CAST((USCounties2010.P0010001+USCounties2000.p0010001) AS numeric(8,1)),0) AS 'total_populace'
FROM
            (SELECT 
                        STUSAB,
                        COUNT(*) AS '#'
            FROM USCounties2010
            GROUP BY STUSAB)
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT 
                        state_us_abbreviation,
                        SUM(p0010001) AS 'st_populace'
            FROM USCounties2000
            GROUP BY state_us_abbreviation)
            ON USCounties2010.STUSAB=USCounties2000.state_us_abbeviation
ORDER BY ROUND(CAST((USCounties2010.P0010001+USCounties2000.p0010001) AS numeric(8,1)),0) DESC;
```

The following syntax error is displayed after execution. I tried several times to rectify this but in vain. Please help. Two different datasets have been used, **us_counties_2010** and **us_counties_2000**.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 50
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
```

After incorporating the necessary changes, still the issue persists. Kindly refer below:

```
SELECT
            C_2010.STUSAB,
            C_2010.P0010001,
            C_2000.p0010001,
            ROUND(CAST((C_2010.P0010001+C_2000.p0010001) AS numeric(8,1)),0) AS 'total_populace'
FROM
            (SELECT 
                        STUSAB,
                        SUM(P0010001) AS 'P0010001',
                        COUNT(*) AS '#'
            FROM USCounties2010
            GROUP BY STUSAB) AS 'C_2010'
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT 
                        state_us_abbreviation,
                        SUM(p0010001) AS 'p0010001'
            FROM USCounties2000
            GROUP BY state_us_abbreviation) AS 'C_2000'
            ON C_2010.STUSAB=C_2000.state_us_abbeviation
ORDER BY ROUND(CAST((C_2010.P0010001+C_2000.p0010001) AS numeric(8,1)),0) DESC;
```

Output:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 50
Incorrect syntax near 'C_2010'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Comment: Please do not SHOUT at us; it is considered rude.

Comment: Your derived tables have no aliases; a derived table **must** have an alias.

Comment: You also attempt to reference columns in your outer query that don't exist in either of your derived tables. For example, neither define a column called `P0010001`.

Comment: Add an alias to the table expression. For example, change `GROUP BY STUSAB)` to `GROUP BY STUSAB) x`. That `x` there is the alias. You should do it too to the other table expression (using a different alias. The `ON` clause should reference these aliases.

Comment: Just a note, a subquery in the FROM clause is called a _derived table_.

Answer (score 1):

To help explain the issue, I'm gonna narrow down the code to this excerpt to focus in on the first subquery:

```
FROM
    (SELECT 
        STUSAB,
        COUNT(*) AS '#'
     FROM USCounties2010
     GROUP BY STUSAB
    )
    INNER JOIN
```

Note the closing parentheses, which I moved to it's own line to help it stand out, followed by the `INNER JOIN`. SQL Server **requires** you to give subqueries like this an [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) in order to use them this way.

So you can correct it like this:

```
FROM
    (SELECT 
        STUSAB,
        COUNT(*) AS '#'
     FROM USCounties2010
     GROUP BY STUSAB
    ) c2010
    INNER JOIN
```

You must do the same thing for the other subquery.

Then, in the `SELECT` and `ON` lists, use the aliases instead of the original table name:

```
SELECT c2010.STUSAB, c2010.P0010001, ...
```

Finally, that `P0010001` doesn't exist in the subquery, meaning it's no longer available for use in the `SELECT` list. Instead, it seems likely you want the `#` and `st_populace` named aggregate fields:

```
SELECT c2010.STUSAB, c2010.[#], c2000.st_populace ...
```

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't define any columns called `P0010001` in their derived tables. The have the columns `STUSAB`, `#`, `state_us_abbreviation`, `st_populace`, so `c2010.P0010001` is still going to error.

Comment: @ThomA Good point. Adding a section for that.

Comment: Thanks for your support. The same issue persists after making the necessary changes.

Comment: @SAAD don't use quotes for the alias names

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It does, @SAAD . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L98sL4W9)

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly name your subquery tables in FROM using 'AS'. The format you are going for is like this:

```
SELECT a.Field1, a.Field2, b.Field3
FROM (subquery statement a) AS a
INNER JOIN
     (subquery statement b) AS b
ON a.FieldMatch=b.FieldMatch
```

Your main SELECT statement does not *know* you are calling from a subquery on USCounties2010 -- you must *name* it USCounties2010. Only then can you refer to *Name.Column* (USCounties2010.STUSAB and so on) both in your SELECT and after the ON.

That should fix your error. Note that you will likely encounter your next error by calling column names that you have not selected in the subqueries (P001...). Your current FROM dataset is only retrieving these columns:

```
STUSAB
#
state_us_abbreviation
st_populace
```

... so those are the only columns available for your main SELECT to utilize.

Comment: Technically, the `As` is optional. Instead of `AS a` it's perfectly legal to just have the `a`.

Comment: Thanks for your support. The same issue persists after making the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the population of the counties per state should be summed up. Then they should be put out together in a list and sorted in descending order of population.

I generally don't use 'SubQueries'. I prefer a 'CTE'. In the 'CTE' I can then rename the columns. This makes the final select easier to read.

In the ORDER BY you can use the column 'total_populace' because it is already known here.

Here is my solution (swap the 'City' column with 'Counties'):

```
WITH USCounties2000 AS ( -- give me a table with the population city in states in 2000
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES  ('Akron          ','OH',188509)
            , ('Cincinnati     ','OH',309513)
            , ('Cleveland      ','OH',361607)
            , ('Columbus       ','OH',907971)
            , ('Dayton         ','OH',135944)
            , ('Toledo         ','OH',266301)
            , ('Broken Arrow   ','OK',117911)
            , ('Norman         ','OK',129627)
            , ('Oklahoma City  ','OK',694800)
            , ('Tulsa          ','OK',411867)
    )  AS t (city, state_us_abbreviation, P0010001)
)
, USCounties2010 AS ( -- give me a table with the population city in states in 2010
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES  ('Akron          ','OH',190469)
            , ('Cincinnati     ','OH',309317)
            , ('Cleveland      ','OH',372624)
            , ('Columbus       ','OH',905748)
            , ('Dayton         ','OH',137644)
            , ('Toledo         ','OH',270871)
            , ('Broken Arrow   ','OK',113540)
            , ('Norman         ','OK',128026)
            , ('Oklahoma City  ','OK',681054)
            , ('Tulsa          ','OK',413066)
    )  AS t (city, STUSAB, P0010001)
)
, USC2000Sum AS (
SELECT state_us_abbreviation
    , COUNT(*) AS '#'
    , SUM(p0010001) AS 'st_populace'
FROM USCounties2000
GROUP BY state_us_abbreviation
)
, USC2010Sum AS (
SELECT STUSAB AS state_us_abbreviation
    , COUNT(*) AS '#'
    , SUM(p0010001) AS 'st_populace'
FROM USCounties2010
GROUP BY STUSAB
)
SELECT USC2010Sum.state_us_abbreviation
    , USC2010Sum.st_populace AS st_populace_2010
    , USC2000Sum.st_populace AS st_populace_2000
    , USC2000Sum.# AS st_#_2010
    , USC2010Sum.# AS st_#_2000
    , ROUND(CAST((USC2010Sum.st_populace+USC2000Sum.st_populace) AS numeric(8,1)),0) AS total_populace
FROM USC2010Sum
    INNER JOIN USC2000Sum ON USC2010Sum.state_us_abbreviation=USC2000Sum.state_us_abbreviation
ORDER BY total_populace DESC
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/JgrP69V-)